# Water wheel turning a fan motor and voltmeter shows approximately 300 VDC. How to charge batteries from that?

Tags: battery-charging, dc-motor, power-generation

I’m trying to create something to produce enough power to keep a bank of batteries (wired for 24 volt configuration) charged. Basically I'm using six to eight 12 volt batteries, wired to a 24 VDC to 110 VAC inverter.

I have a couple of streams, where I’ve managed to collect water that runs down a 2 1/2” tube with a drop of 20 feet onto a water wheel, which is connected to a ceiling fan motor (I believe).  When the wheel is turning, I check the fan motor wires with a voltmeter. On the 500 VDC range, it reads a pretty consistent 300 volts.

If anyone could give me a better idea to achieve my need, please respond.  And if I’m really generating 300 VDC, what can I do with it to charge the bank of batteries?

Thank you.

Comment: What is "confrigeration"? What is "a couple stream"? Would a 24 V alternator not be a better job?

Comment: Ceiling fan motors normally run on AC so I doubt if that's generating 300VDC at any useful level of power.

Comment: You should first verify that the motor is producing DC and that the voltage does not drop when you attach a dummy load like a heater. If you have a reliable DC source, you need a DC to DC converter to efficiently reduce the voltage to a useable level to connect to a battery charging controller.

Comment: Open-circuit voltage will be misleading. Attach a 60W light bulb to that water wheel (when it's stopped), then see what happens when you let go. And make sure of course that all the wiring is well insulated and that you're not holding anything in your hands when you turn the circuit back on (other than touching the switch).

Comment: Simplest way to convert 150-400VDC is to feed it to just about any universal input switching power supply (which is nearly all power supplies these days). These rectify the mains input to 350-400VDC internally and will sometimes run on DC power just as well. E.g. your phone charger will likely be able to convert 300VDC into 5VDC. ***Safety Disclaimer:*** *300V electronics can be **deadly**, always remember the golden rule, when dealing with **live high voltage**, keep one hand fully gloved, in your pocket or otherwise **well insulated**, this keeps any accidental currents away from the heart.*